# HBase Shell works but Unable to connect to Web UI

Tags: macos, hadoop, localhost, hbase, hadoop2

Following the [2. Quick Start - Standalone HBase](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_introduction) instructions I installed HBase standalone on my Macbook. The shell works - I can create tables, drop tables, etc.

However, I can't seem to get the Web UI working. I've tried a variety of configurations for the hbase-site.xml file. I <s>don't get any</s> *get one* HBase errors *that I don't think is related*, but I get "Unable to connect" from the browser.

Has anyone else had this issue and solved it?

Errors:

```
Thu Nov  1 06:26:42 PDT 2018 Starting master on USERS-MacBook-Pro.local
.
.
.
2018-11-01 06:26:49,477 INFO  [main] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2018-11-01 06:26:49,621 ERROR [main] server.ZooKeeperServer: ZKShutdownHandler is not registered, so ZooKeeper server won't take any action on ERROR or SHUTDOWN server state changes
2018-11-01 06:26:49,632 INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181] server.NIOServerCnxnFactory: Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:56148
.
.
.
2018-11-01 06:26:50,248 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are you trying with hue?

Comment: @NishuTayal I'm not. I'm trying to access it at http://localhost:16010/

Comment: Still no solution. Currently I have hbase.rootdir pointing to a local directory and do not have hbase.master.port or hbase.master.info.port set. Not sure if that helps with troubleshooting here.

Comment: did you check in the logs if there is any error?

Comment: @NishuTayal I get 1 error that I don't think is related. I added it above.

Comment: Hi did you resolve this issue maybe_ if you are please provide me with info how. Thanks